# htaccess file in custom mvc application

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm building my own MVC application with php. index.php will be the front controller.
In index.php i will take the parameters with $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], so i need my

.htaccess file to redirect /attr1/attr2/attr3 to index.php?attr1/attr2/attr3.

($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] doesn't work properly)

if my htaccess file (apache server) is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
</IfModule>
```

query_string outputs index.php
but if i access url via localhost/something/attr1/attr2/attr3 and .htaccess is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(something)\/(.*)$ index.php?$2
</IfModule>
```

query_string is printing attr1/attr2/attr3

WTF??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

and then the url will be in the $_GET array (the 4th and 5th lines ensure the rule applies when there is no actual file at that path)

Comment: nice!! So i had to put this RewriteCond! I'll study them better! thanks a lot!!